# ubuntu-make didn't install in specified location

Tags: directory, android-studio, ubuntu-make

I installed Android Studio using `umake android`. It asked for a location to install it in. After the installation the location is empty. *(I'm sure I'm at the correct directory)*

How do I fix this? How do I *correctly* move android studio after it's installed? *It's okay if I have to uninstall and reinstall it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Apparently `umake` currently doesn't recognise quotes in input directories. I found android studio in my home folder in a directory named quote (`~\'\...`) LOL XD

...so till things get fixed let's not enter directories withen quotes. [**reports to launchpad**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-make/+bug/1584152) XD