# how to install android studio with umake and snap? ubuntu-make.umake usage

Tags: java, application-development, snap, android-studio, ubuntu-make

How do [install](https://askubuntu.com/q/969080/45156) android-studio from umake through snap?  It seems to be a matter of `umake` usage...but the command looks [correct](https://askubuntu.com/q/775269/45156).

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap install ubuntu-make
error: This revision of snap "ubuntu-make" was published using classic confinement and thus
       may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security sandbox that snaps are
       usually confined to, which may put your system at risk.

       If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including --classic.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap install ubuntu-make --classic
ubuntu-make master from 'didrocks' installed
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ubuntu-make.umake android
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
thufir@dur:~$
```

This appears to be the [suggested](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/474) method.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: what is the command to install android studio?  with snap package for umake.

Comment: I believe this is your original post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/969552/ubuntu-make-umake-android-segmentation-fault

Comment: It appears to be a bug as I see the same thing on my end. Your install method is ok!

Comment: thanks, George.  Didn't want to go too far down the rabbit hole trying to figure that out.

Comment: This is being discussed in the forum via: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/where-how-is-umake-installed-usage/2615

Answer (score 2):

In https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make

If you use the Ubuntu Make snap to ensure you always have the latest and greatest version, even on older supported releases.

Install:

```
snap install ubuntu-make --classic
```

Umake can then be run as `ubuntu-make.umake`

Run Ubuntu Make:

```
snap run ubuntu-make.umake android
```

Comment: as from the comments, there was a [bug](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/where-how-is-umake-installed-usage/2615).  sounds like it was resolved.  but, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is no longer required, if you installed using

```
snap install ubuntu-make --classic
```

you then need to reboot your system so snap is in your path.  After that you can simply run.

```
umake android
```